# Infinite prime numbers from a sum of powers

Tags: number-theory

I am not sure if it's possible to get infinite prime numbers from this sum:
$$p=k^j+j^k$$
with $j\in\mathbb{N}, k\in\mathbb{N}$
I tried for $j=1,2,...9,k=1,2,...9$ and I get only eleven prime numbers.
If I consider the matrix:
$$A(k,j)=k^j+j^k$$
in which the components $A(j,k)=1$ iff $p$ is prime
this is a sparse matrix in which the prime numbers are mostly in the first four rows. Can someone give me some hint to prove $A$ contains infinite prime numbers in the limit $j\to \infty$, $k\to\infty$

Comment: Why is $A(k,j)$ a sparse matrix? It seems to pretty much always non-zero.

Comment: Also, this is not a diophantine equation, because there are variables in the exponent.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: In fact it isn't a Diophantine equation. Sorry, but $A$ is the matrix in which the component are non zero iff the number $A(j,k)$ is prime.

Comment: You wrote $A(k,j)$ for a function and $A(j,k)$ for the matrix elements, which is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** You get infinitely many primes when $k=1$ or $j=1$.

Comment: It would be interesting if from the equation in $p$ it's possible to get infinite primes, for $j\gt 1$ and $k\gt 1$